# Maverick not recognizing my sound card

Tags: 10.10, sound

I've installed Maverick on a Sony Vaio VPCEA24FM. I have no sound. I've gone through the guide at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting up to the section titled, "Is the system recognizing your sound card?" When I run the terminal command in that step:

```
sudo aplay -l
```

I get the following response:

```
aplay: device_list:235: no soundcards found...
```

The machine does actually have an onboard soundcard; it works fine when I run Windows.

When I run hardware lister (lshw-gtk), this is what shows up for audio:
[image]

Can anyone help me out? I really want to switch over to Linux completely, but I can't do it if I don't have working sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did finally get it to work by using the ALSA upgrade script on [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=6589810). The first time I ran it, I got compile errors when running this line:

```
sudo ./AlsaUpgrade-1.0.23-2.sh -c
```

I went back and ran

```
sudo ./AlsaUpgrade-1.0.23-2.sh -s
```

to get the snapshot ALSA release for Maverick, and that did it.